# How to configure database in Blackberry enterprise server?

Tags: sql-server, bes

I have downloaded Trial - BlackBerry Enterprise Server 4.1 for MDS Applications. Tried to install the same.but unable to configure Database settings.
Am using MS SQL Server

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86) Jul 9 2008 14:43:34 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6001: Service Pack 1)
```

But while configuration its prompting me an error.

```
"Your database environment must be Microsoft SQL server 2000 SP3a or later"
```

Can anybody help me where am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BES 4.1 is old, and I don't think it supports SQL 2008. BES 5.x should work fine however.

Comment: but all BES 5.x have there prerequisite,like MS Exchange sever,etc. Is it possible to use push service on BES without these Prerequisite,as I think they deal with requirements related to emails,and my requirement is just send a message to push enabled client,I am very new to BB development,so might be going wrong some where,Will be glad if someone correct me. Thanx

Comment: While the BES components can be installed separately on different machines, they all work together as a whole. A BES MDS connection server does you no good without the other components.

Comment: @joeqwetry:Thanx for the Reply.So in that case, I guess 3  option left BES with Exchange server or Novell or Dommino. Can you please suggest me which is better for Push service.I have 32 bit Windows Vista as OS so I guess in that enviorment I will not be able to use Exchange server,Now which is better Novell or Dommion?? Hope for a help